# Checking DNS via command line script

Tags: batch-file, command-line, dns

I have a couple of systems in my office with incorrect DNS Settings....

I wanna do a sweep of all systems.

how can I check if my systems have the correct DNS?

ie my DNS address is 1.1.1.1?

Thanks in advance.
This is what i was working on.
    @echo off
    REM This is to check DNS

```
set dnsAddy= "ipconfig /all | findstr Servers | findstr /V 1.1.1.1"
If %dnsAddy% = null then
exit 0
fi echo "DNS is incorrect"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isDns.bat

```
ipconfig /all | findstr "Servers" | findstr "1.1.1.1"
```

If you wanted to pass the IP address in

```
ipconfig /all | findstr "Servers" | findstr "%1"
```

To use the 2nd version you would type `isDns 1.1.1.1` from a command prompt.

In either case you will get no output if the DNS entry does not match.

---

---

Edit following question clarification

```
ipconfig /all | findstr "Servers" | findstr "1.1.1.1"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (echo "You're good!") ELSE (echo "Bad config")
```

Comment: Sorry for being unclear... i tried to show that i made an attempt at figuring this out before posting.
Yes this will be a bat file that i would like to run on each system and report whether DNS is set correctly or not.

Comment: So you want to run a bat file on each machine? Will the DNS be the same for each or do you need to pass in the proper DNS entry?

Comment: DNS will be the same for each

Comment: That's as far as i got... but i wanted a an IF Then statement.
I modified my original question... thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure it out in command... but i was able to put this vbscript together. and it works.

```
Dim objShell, myDNS, myDNScmd
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.shell")
myDNScmd = "ipconfig /all | findstr ""Servers"" | findstr /V 1.1.1.1"
myDNS = objShell.run ("%comspec% /c " & myDNScmd,0,True)
'wscript.echo myDNS
If myDNS = 1 then
    'wscript.echo "CORRECT - DNS Server is set to 1.1.1.1"
    wscript.quit 0
else
    'wscript.echo "WRONG - DNS Server is not set to 1.1.1.1"
    wscript.quit 123456
end if
objShell.Close
```